# Contact Form not sending all information

Tags: php, forms, contacts

checked all other resources before asking but it did not answer my question. Anyways, why am I not receiving all information? Thanks.

Here's my PHP:

```
    <?php

$message = "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
$message .= "\r\nPhone " . $_POST['phone'];
$message .= "\r\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Form of Contact: " . $_POST['reach'];
$message .= "\r\nEvent Type: " . $_POST['event'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Dates: " . $_POST['date'];
$message .= "\r\nNumber of Attendees: " . $_POST['attendees'];
$message .= "\r\nOvernight Guests: " . $_POST['overnight'];
$message .= "\r\nMeals Included?: " . $_POST['meals'];
$message .= "\r\nAdditional Information: " . $_POST['message'];

$to = 'nosdg@testfakel.com'; 
$email_subject = "Fake Subject"; 
$email_body = $message;
$headers = "From: iauto@can.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
   <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Best way for us to reach back to you:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reach">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Type of event: (ex. sports/wedding/business) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Date or Weekend Desired (ex. 4/16-4/25) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Number of Attendees:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attendees">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Overnight Guests</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="overnight">
                    </div>

                </div>
                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Meals Included? (Yes/No/Maybe)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meals"> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Additional Information:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" maxlength="39999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
            </form>
```

Any idea why I am only receiving Name, phone, Email , and Additional Info?

Thank you!!

Comment: You need to use the 'name' attribute.  You are currently only using the 'id' attribute.

Comment: You have to give those input elements a 'name' attribute. I don't know why you receive some of them, though they don't have such an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this form and please share javascript code(if you used)

```
 <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name='name'>
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name='phone'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  name='email'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Best way for us to reach back to you:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reach"  name='reach'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Type of event: (ex. sports/wedding/business) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event"  name='event'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Date or Weekend Desired (ex. 4/16-4/25) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date"  name='date'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Number of Attendees:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attendees"  name='attendees'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Overnight Guests</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="overnight"  name='overnight'>
                    </div>

                </div>
                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Meals Included? (Yes/No/Maybe)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meals" name='meals'> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Additional Information:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" name='name' maxlength="39999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Posting as a community wiki.**

`<form>` defaults to a GET method if omitted. **(consult my footnotes)**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

so add a POST method:

```
<form method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

since you are using POST arrays.

Then all your inputs do not bear the name attribute and you're relying on an id only.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and do the same for the rest of your inputs.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

If you're using JS/Ajax with this that you didn't post and I suspect that you are, then edit your question with the code you're really using.

- **The problem may very well be in there, so check your (JS) console.**